# Python shelve module why is this code fast, but the other slow?

Tags: python, database, shelve

The output of the code below is

```
fast: 0.018553733825683594
slow: 7.0305609703063965
```

and, more than that, the file of slow.dat is 10,252KB while fast.dat is only 32KB. Why is the fast one small.. fast and small while slow.... is so slow and big?

```
import shelve
import random
import time

start = time.time()
db = shelve.open('fast') 

db["answers"] = []
answers = []

for i in range(1000):
    answer = {
        "foo0": random.randint(1,10),
        "foo1": random.randint(1,10),
        "foo2": random.randint(1,10),
        "foo3": random.randint(1,10),
        "foo4": random.randint(1,10),
        "foo5": random.randint(1,10)
    }
    answers.append(answer)

db['answers'] = answers
db.close()
print("fast:", time.time() - start)


start = time.time()
db = shelve.open('slow') # slow and uses !!!!WAY MORE SPACE!!!!
db["answers"] = []

for i in range(1000):
    answer = {
        "foo0": random.randint(1,10),
        "foo1": random.randint(1,10),
        "foo2": random.randint(1,10),
        "foo3": random.randint(1,10),
        "foo4": random.randint(1,10),
        "foo5": random.randint(1,10)
    }
    db['answers'] = db['answers'] + [answer]

db.close()
print("slow:", time.time() - start)
```

Comment: Maybe if you try writeback=True as the docs suggest, it may solve something (but consume more memory due to caching) https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html

Comment: @skywalker it helped a little in both regards, speed, and file size, but not even a little close to the fast example

Comment: I tested it and it decreased the time tenfold. (From 2.18s to 0.29s) The file is still large but smaller.

Comment: `db = shelve.open('slow', writeback=True)` `fast: 0.016541242599487305
slow: 6.1413116455078125` @skywalker

Comment: @skywalker tried with .append, seemed to work.. post answer if you want I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) say that shelve has problems with knowing whether a mutable structure has been modified. They suggest using `writeback=True` which caches the structures in memory and writes them on `.sync` and `.close`.

This improved the required time and space by little but OP said that also using `.append` on these lists solves the problem.

If there are still problems I would suggest using a better-suited database to your situation than `shelve`.

Comment: note: writeback=True AND append solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are appending to a list, in the second you are are creating a new list in each iteration of the loop.

`mylist.append(obj)` -> add to existing list

`mylist = mylist + [obj]` -> combines two lists to make a new list.

Creating a new list each time is more expensive than just appending.

`mylist += [obj]` is probably what you want - this is the same as appending - same action, different syntax.

Comment: It theoretically makes sense to me, but I just tried  `db['answers'] += [answer]` and it's still slow, by the same amount. Also the file is still wayyyy bigger than it should be

Comment: @AlexMortez maybe shelve does unnecessary IO with every assignment? (I don't know about file size though)